# Inappropriate Encoding of response of Scrapy

Tags: python, utf-8, character-encoding, scrapy

When I tried out the `Scrapy` yesterday, I was trying to fetch the titles of the posts of a Chinese Ruby forum. But, somehow the outputs of the `Scrapy` are all `Unicode`, like

```
"[\u5317\u4eac][2017\u5e746\u670818\u65e5] Rails Girls"
```

I've checked out the encoding of the response is `UTF-8` and I printed out the content of body which show the Chinese chars correctly.

So, I'm confused of that why I use Scrapy selector to pick the title and put the output to a Json file. Then, the content of the file are all character pointers, like `\u5317`. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

My code:

```
import scrapy

class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
  name = 'myspider'
  start_urls = ['https://ruby-china.org/topics']

  def parse(self, response):
    self.logger.warning("body: %s", response.body)
    for topic in response.css('div.topic'):
        title = topic.css('div.media-heading')
        yield {'title': title.css('a ::attr(title)').extract_first()}
```

Answer (score 2):

When Scrapy calls your callback with a response for a URL, the response contains the decoded Unicode body content, as `response.text`, and the "raw" bytes of the received body, in whatever encoding was use, as `response.body`.

When you use Scrapy selectors that you get from `response.xpath()` or `response.css()` calls, and you call `.extract()` on them, you get Python Unicode strings.

Python 2.7 uses `\uXXXX` escapes sequences to represent them. That's what you see in the console logs of the yielded items.

But if you call print on those string, you see the characters themselves:

```
$ scrapy shell https://ruby-china.org/topics
2017-05-23 13:15:33 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 1.4.0 started (bot: scrapybot)
(...)
2017-05-23 13:15:33 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2017-05-23 13:15:35 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://ruby-china.org/topics> (referer: None)
(...)
>>> for topic in response.css('div.topic'):
...     title = topic.css('div.media-heading')
...     print(title.css('a ::attr(title)').extract_first())
... 
[北京][2017年6月18日] Rails Girls 复活啦 2017 北京活动报名 | 少女们一天学编程
招 ruby 开发偏执狂,分享产品成果
challenge #1
[上海／成都] Le Wagon 编程训练营招聘 Ruby 导师，2200/ 天
量产型炮灰工程师
如果开发公众号内的小应用，rails 前端搭配哪个框架，vue？react？angular？
[长沙] Kdan Mobile 招聘 Ruby on Rails 工程师 (9K～15K)
Ruby 开发有什么新的进展吗？PHP 貌似要上 JIT 了！
这种需要强行增加对象阅读数，有其他建议吗？
rails 项目，production 模式在 ie8 下报"'undefined' 为空或不是对象"错误
pwc (sdc) 招后端，前端，区块链应用开发。
我想做个类似 app 中的消息中心,比如我下完订单,就会提示我订单的状态!
[上海] 郎客信息技术有限公司招聘 Rails 实习生 2 名
Rails 5.1 使用 yarn 和 webpack 实战 (vue, 构建等)
 [上海] 赛若福诚聘 Ruby 工程师
[上海&杭州] Change 健身潮流文化社区招收 Ruby 工程师 (15-40k 十四薪)
[宁波] 新希望软件 Ruby 工程师 3 名 [8k~12k] 
如何禁用下拉列表
為你自己學 Ruby on Rails
使用 RSpec 在 Rails 5 下测试邮件的发送
GitHub API v4 改用 GraphQL 了
[上海] 2017.5.21 Elixir Meetup
多态情况下关联表查询问题
Rails 与 Django 性能的疑问
[北京] 西单，金融方向，欢迎 Ruby 大牛 [15k~30k]
云梯正式开通 Telegram 官方频道
>>>
```

Now, if you export your items as JSON, for example with `-o items.json`, by default, Scrapy will as well write `\uXXXX` escape sequences in JSON strings of the different items. It's the same as how Python 2.7 represent non-ASCII characters, and that's 100% valid JSON output, and is actually the default for Python's `json` module (referred to as `ensure_ascii`).

If you really do need UTF-8 characters in the JSON output file, you can use Scrapy's [`FEED_EXPORT_ENCODING='utf-8'` setting](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/feed-exports.html#std:setting-FEED_EXPORT_ENCODING).